# How to remove the div content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to remove the div content? I am getting data from server regularly. I check if div height is "100" .

Then it remove content and write data from top in jQuery.
I tried very thing nothing is working for me.

```
var scrollerDivHeight=$('#scroller').height();
if(scrollerDivHeight==100){

    //   $('#scroller').val()='';
    $('#scroller' ).innerHTML = '';
    $("#scroller").empty();
    $('#scroller').val('');
    $('#scroller').html('');
    $('#scroller').refresh();


    myScroll.refresh();
}
```

Comment: have you tried .hide()?

Comment: It should work, does it really pass the if statement? Put an alert in it and see if it does that

Comment: `html('')` or `empty()` should work fine. My guess is that height is not equal to `100`. Can you put an example in a fiddle.

Comment: `$('#scroller' ).innerHTML = '';` should fail, because `$('#scroller' )` will return you an object related to `jquery`. You could pull a native DOM object first: `$('#scroller' )[0].innerHTML = '';`

Comment: `$('#scroller' ).innerHTML = '';` is wrong however... should be `$('#scroller' )[0].innerHTML = '';` but I agree, the script don't pass the `if` statement

Comment: Can we see your html as well

Comment: Remove the ? innerHTML` assignment as it will most certainly create a JS error (see comment from @Jari). And don't use alert - put a `console.log('in cleaning code')` and check if it is written to the console. After the `if` add `else console.log('scrollerDivHeight='+scrollerDivHeight);` so you see whats really happening.

Comment: @1ntello for what reason? it's a question related to jQuery.

Comment: see here it is not working http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/rgeHe/8/

Comment: First, there is no scroller id in your fiddle and second the height never goes to 150, it's either 100 or 200 in your fiddle

Comment: @Vallentin what if he has his id wrong or something

Answer (score 0):

Us the Empty() method in jquery

```
   setInterval(function () {
       $('#realtime').append("Hiiiii. is div").css("line-height", "100px");
         var scrollerDivHeight=$('#realtime').height();
       if(scrollerDivHeight>100){
           $("#realtime").empty();
       }
   }, 1000);
```

See fiddle  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/rgeHe/10/)

Read [Jquery Empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) Documentation here

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing this with your code

```
var scrollerDivHeight=$('#scroller').height();
if(scrollerDivHeight >= 100){
    $('#scroller').replaceWith('<div id="scroller"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use > not ==  also fix the id

```
   setInterval(function () {
       $('#scroller').append("Hiiiii. is div").css("line-height", "100px");
         var scrollerDivHeight=$('#scroller').height();
       //alert(scrollerDivHeight)
       console.log(scrollerDivHeight)
       if(scrollerDivHeight>100){
           $("#scroller").empty();
       }
   }, 1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/rgeHe/9/)